# New RTX 3070 GPU causes all kinds of out-of-memory issues

Tags: gpu

Greetings Blender community,
I have recently had the chance to get an RTX 3070 Ti, specifically the Game Rock version. However, it has been causing me all kinds of issues for some reason.

Originally, my main goal was to pair it with the RTX 3060 I already have and for them to work in tandem with each other, as I had done some research before and learned that blender does not require an SLI/NVLink bridge for them to work together.

Ever since I have had both GPUs in the system it has been causing out of memory. I do not have the exact error codes at hand now. But sometimes it would outright crash the app altogether. The errors were something along the lines of "Out of memory in CULauchKernel" or "Out of memory in CUDA enqueue queue".

What makes me most frustrated is that when it comes to gaming or stress testing the GPU, everything checks out and it performs just as you would expect a 3070 Ti to perform.

Even when the 3070 Ti is the only GPU in the system, it still produces tons of out of memory issues, while working perfectly fine in gaming.

Finally, I would like to mention that I am on Blender 3.0, and the render engine I use is CUDA while only selecting the GPU(s). Any help would be of great assistance.

Comment: Have you tried switching to OptiX?